# I am developing application where I only used share package, since then I keep receiving errors

Tags: flutter, dart, share

I am developing application where I only used share package, since then I keep receiving errors that i didnt even how to fix them.
I am developing application where I only used share package, since then I keep receiving errors that i didnt even how to fix them.

here is  my code

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:share/share.dart';
import 'nupe_file.dart';
void main() {
  runApp(const MyApp());
}
class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({Key? key}) : super(key: key);
 @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      home: const MyHomePage(title: 'Flutter Demo Home Page'),
    );
  }
}
class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  const MyHomePage({Key? key, required this.title}) : super(key: key);
  final String title;
  @override
  State<MyHomePage> createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}
class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {  
  final controller = TextEditingController();
  List<WordList> words = dictionary;
  List<String> listWords = worda;
  List<String> listMeanings = meaninga;
  share(BuildContext context,) {
    final RenderObject? box = context.findRenderObject();
    Share.share(
      'https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.codingempirenigeria.fadlullahibilhakimusa',
    );
  }
  aboutMsg(BuildContext context){   
    return showDialog(
      context: context,
      builder: (context){
        return AlertDialog(
          title: Text('About The App'),
          content: Container(
            child: Column(
              children: [
                Text('some information about the application')
              ]
            )
          ),
          actions: [
            FlatButton(
              child: Text('OK'),
              onPressed: () => Navigator.pop(context)
            ),
            FlatButton(
              child: Text('Share'),
              onPressed: share(context)
            )
          ]
        );
      }
    );
  }  
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
         appBar: AppBar(           
           title: Center(
             child: Text('Nupe / English Dictionary'),
           ),
           actions: [
            IconButton(
              icon: Icon(Icons.message_rounded, size: 30),
              onPressed: (){aboutMsg(context);},
            )
          ],
           elevation: 0.0,
         ),
         body: Container(
           child: Column(
             children: [
               Container(
                 color: Colors.blue,
                 padding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(10, 0, 10, 10),
                 child: TextField(
                   controller: controller,
                  scrollPadding: EdgeInsets.all(50),
                  decoration: InputDecoration(
                    contentPadding: EdgeInsets.only(top: 5, left:15),
                    filled: true,
                    fillColor: Colors.white,
                    border: OutlineInputBorder(
                      borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(5),
                    ),
                    hintText: 'Enter Nupe/English Word...',
                    suffixIcon: Icon(Icons.search)                   
                  ),
                  onChanged: search,
                ),
               ),
               Container(                 
                 child: Expanded(
                    child: ListView.builder(
                    itemCount: words.length,                  
                    itemBuilder: (BuildContext contex, int index){
                      final word = words[index];
                      final listWord = listWords[index];
                      final listMeaning = listMeanings[index];
                      return ListTile(
                      tileColor: Colors.white,
                      onTap: null,
                      title: Text(word.word,
                        style: TextStyle(color: Colors.black,
                          fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                        ),
                      ),
                      subtitle: Text(word.meaning,
                        style: TextStyle(color: Colors.black),
                      ),
                    );
                  }
                ),
                ),
              )
            ],
          ),
         ),
      );
  }
  void search(String value) {
    final suggestions = dictionary.where((word) {
      final wordd = word.word.toLowerCase();
      final input = value.toLowerCase();
      return wordd.contains(input);
    }).toList();
    setState(() => words = suggestions);
  }
}
```

here is error I keep recieving

```
/C:/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/mime-1.0.2/lib/src/mime_multipart_transformer.dart: Error: The control character U+0000 can only be used in strings and comments.
/C:/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/mime-1.0.2/lib/src/mime_type.dart: Error: The control character U+0000 can only be used in strings and comments.
/C:/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/share-2.0.4/lib/share.dart:99:12: Error: Method not found: 'lookupMimeType'.
    return lookupMimeType(path) ?? 'application/octet-stream';
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
* Where:
Script 'C:\flutter\packages\flutter_tools\gradle\flutter.gradle' line: 1102
* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:compileFlutterBuildDebug'.
> Process 'command 'C:\flutter\bin\flutter.bat'' finished with non-zero exit value 1
* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org
BUILD FAILED in 4m 58s
Exception: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1
Exited (sigterm)
```

Comment: please read what you wrote

Comment: Can you try using share_plus? share is deprecated.

Answer (score 0):

Use this flutter_share: ^2.0.0 package

```
 Future<void> share() async {
    await FlutterShare.share(
        title: 'Example share',
        text: 'Example share text',
        linkUrl: 'https://flutter.dev/',
        chooserTitle: 'Example Chooser Title');
  }
```